# Eclipse / ADT not updating package when re-running after editing XML

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

So this is probably a dumb question as I'm just dipping my feet into Android App development. Im using Eclipse / ADT build 21.1.0. and am running through the android developer tutorial found at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html.

Which, the above link is where I'm hitting an odd snag. Following the instructions, editing the XML, then running the emulator, the app refuses to show the text fields and continues to show Hello World.

I have to assume theres a build function to update the edited XML files, but this is not described in the tutorial, and Ive followed the editing instructions specifically, I cant figure out how to update the R.java file with my new edits (tutorial suggests it does this automatically).

I know I'm making a rookie mistake... But have been unable to find a solution to move forward.

Furthermore, Im getting this on first run:

---

[2013-02-27 12:36:38 - MyFirstApp] W/ResourceType( 5128): Bad XML block: header size 284 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-02-27 12:36:38 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\jkyle\workspace\MyFirstApp\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').

---

I run it again, it runs and it says all is well.

Any help is mucho appreciated.

Comment: for the beginning try to clean the project and then run it. If the problem is not resolved check if you have defined the string `action_settings` in `strings.xml`

Comment: my strings.xml file looks like this:


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>`


I did a clean and its still telling me the errors exist. Let me look into the action settings bit.

Comment: then add an entry like `<string name="action_settings">action Settings</string>` in `strings.xml`

Comment: @niculare That did it... No mention of that bit in the tut as far as I can see. Did make me figure out what the action_settings are tho. All works and Im able to move on. Thanks you for your time!

Comment: I will add my answer and please accept it by clicking the check mark:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an entry like `<string name="action_settings">action Settings</string>` in `strings.xml`